# TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference. The object isn't null

Tags: actionscript-3

Okay, so my game codes are not problematic at all and don't effect the game UNLESS I declare the level "OneManager" as a variable.

OneManager is the class for my level. The level is a movieclip containing all the level's components. And Main is the document class.

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
at OneManager()[C:\Users\Jay\Creative Cloud Files\Subject 51 Experimental\OneManager.as:38]
at Main()[C:\Users\Jay\Creative Cloud Files\Subject 51 Experimental\Main.as:16]
```

I don't think it makes any sense. I deleted line 38, then the problem indicated until line 39, then I deleted them over and over. Then practically until my code was useless, that's when I FINALLY got no error...

These codes don't even look problematic at all. I even tried adding them manually by adding the class's movieclip to the stage myself and it worked completely fine. But what I'm trying to do is add it to the stage through code by making this class's movieclip a variable and when the button is clicked, but if I did that - I would get these random errors from other classes.

I'm not sure what's wrong here. There is no trouble compiling, so I get no compile errors. Only errors from the output. These lines of codes aren't null, but the output says it is. I'm confused.

Please help, thanks!

Code for Main Document Class:

```
package
{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

public class Main extends MovieClip
{
    var mountains: Mountains;
    var homePage: HomePage;
    var oneManager: OneManager;

    public function Main()
    {
        mountains = new Mountains;
        homePage = new HomePage;
        oneManager = new OneManager;
        addChild(homePage);
        homePage.playButtons.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onPlayButtonsClick);
    }

    function onPlayButtonsClick(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        //var level1Page = new Level1Page;
        removeChild(homePage);
        addChild(oneManager);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Could you provide full source code? Or at least code of `OneManager` class.

Comment: Could you show the code of `OneManager.as` file ?